# Complete Solution for Drawing 1 Pixel Line on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, line

Draw 1 pixel line on HTML5 canvas is always problematic.(Refer to http://jsbin.com/voqubexu/1/edit?js,output)

The approach to draw a vertical/horizontal line is x+0.5, y+0.5 ( Refer to [Canvas line behaviour when 0 < lineWidth < 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669578/canvas-line-behaviour-when-0-linewidth-1)).
To do this globally, `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);` would be a good idea.

However, when it comes to diagonal lines, this method does not work. It always give a 2 pixel line. Is there a way to stop this browser behavior? If not, is there a package that can provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the behavior of the code in that fiddle, with an (0.5, 0.5) offset, and `lineWidth=1, alpha=0.5`, not what you want?  To me, that looks pretty much perfect at all angles.

Comment: The last sample in your bin seems fine. Are you sure you're not trying to fix a physical artefact of the rendering process?

Comment: When You zoom the screenshot You can see that the line is actually thicker than minimal imaginable. It is just brighter and looks like thinner on high resolution screens. Note that the vertical and horisontal sides are also lighter to maintain sameness... they are not black at all. The correct vertical and horisontal blackness can be seen on image no 2... I guess, if nothing helps then one has to draw the pixels using own algorithm directly. Sure that would be slow... so yes, solution needed.

Comment: 0.5 is not always a real size of the pixel. You should get the pixel ratio and divide it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "wider" line you refer to results from anti-aliasing that's automatically done by the browser.

Anti-aliasing is used to display a visually less jagged line.

Short of drawing pixel-by-pixel, there's currently no way of disabling anti-aliasing drawn by the browser.

You can use *Bresenham's line algorithm* to draw your line by setting individual pixels.  Of course, setting individual pixels results in lesser performance.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3j7hpng0/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data=imgData.data;

    bline(50,50,250,250);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);

    function setPixel(x,y){
        var n=(y*canvas.width+x)*4;
        data[n]=255;
        data[n+1]=0;
        data[n+2]=0;
        data[n+3]=255;
    }

    // Refer to: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#JavaScript
    function bline(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      var dx = Math.abs(x1 - x0), sx = x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
      var dy = Math.abs(y1 - y0), sy = y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1; 
      var err = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2;        
      while (true) {
        setPixel(x0,y0);
        if (x0 === x1 && y0 === y1) break;
        var e2 = err;
        if (e2 > -dx) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
        if (e2 < dy) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
      }
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I guess this is the only way to do it before they change the standard.

Comment: Is there any way to change width of line with this algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

For me, only a combination of different 'pixel perfect' techniques helped to archive the results:

1. Get and scale canvas with a pixel ratio:

   **pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio/ctx.backingStorePixelRatio**
2. Scale the canvas on the resize (avoid canvas default stretch scaling).
3. multiple the lineWidth with pixelRatio to find proper 'real' pixel line thickness:

   **context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;**
4. Check whether the thickness of the line is odd or even. add half of the pixelRatio to the line position for the odd thickness values.

   **x = x + pixelRatio/2;**

The odd line will be placed in the middle of the pixel. The line above is used to move it a little bit.

5. use image-rendering: pixelated;

```js
function getPixelRatio(context) {
  dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    bsr = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

  return dpr / bsr;
}


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pixelRatio = getPixelRatio(context);
var initialWidth = canvas.clientWidth * pixelRatio;
var initialHeight = canvas.clientHeight * pixelRatio;


window.addEventListener('resize', function(args) {
  rescale();
  redraw();
}, false);

function rescale() {
  var width = initialWidth * pixelRatio;
  var height = initialHeight * pixelRatio;
  if (width != context.canvas.width)
    context.canvas.width = width;
  if (height != context.canvas.height)
    context.canvas.height = height;

  context.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
}

function pixelPerfectLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  thickness = 1;
  // Multiple your stroke thickness  by a pixel ratio!
  context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;

  context.strokeStyle = "Black";
  context.moveTo(getSharpPixel(thickness, x1), getSharpPixel(thickness, y1));
  context.lineTo(getSharpPixel(thickness, x2), getSharpPixel(thickness, y2));
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function pixelPerfectRectangle(x, y, w, h, thickness, useDash) {
  context.save();
  // Pixel perfect rectange:
  context.beginPath();

  // Multiple your stroke thickness by a pixel ratio!
  context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;
  context.strokeStyle = "Red";
  if (useDash) {
    context.setLineDash([4]);
  }
  // use sharp x,y and integer w,h!
  context.strokeRect(
    getSharpPixel(thickness, x),
    getSharpPixel(thickness, y),
    Math.floor(w),
    Math.floor(h));
  context.restore();
}

function redraw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  pixelPerfectLine(50,50,250,250);
  pixelPerfectLine(120,0,120,250);
  pixelPerfectLine(122,0,122,250);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(10, 11, 200.3, 43.2, 1, false);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(41, 42, 150.3, 43.2, 1, true);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(102, 100, 150.3, 243.2, 2, true);
}

function getSharpPixel(thickness, pos) {

  if (thickness % 2 == 0) {
    return pos;
  }
  return pos + pixelRatio / 2;

}

rescale();
redraw();
```

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Resize event is not fired in the snipped so you can try the file on the [github](https://github.com/ievgennaida/js-animation-timeline-control/blob/master/demo/pixel-perfect-example.html)

Comment: This still gives imperfect lines in Firefox 118